# what happens when i send a different m3u8 to ipad than what it expected?

Tags: ipad, safari, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, m3u

I am prototyping this idea. i have a client/server model wherein whenever a client requests a m3u8 file, say `01.m3u8`.

Based on some conditions I send it 01.m3u8 or some other m3u8 file, say `other.m3u8`.
However, when I send other.m3u8 file, something goes wrong. Ipad takes very long to play the contents of `other.m3u8`.

Can someone please explain what happens in the background in ipad-safari, when you send a different m3u8 from what the ipad expects ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of experimenting, the solution to this is using the #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag. Lookup the spec for m3u8 for a better explanation of the tag.

Hope it helps someone.